# How do I construct an index after conducting a factor analysis?

Tags: factor-analysis

I have a large dataset containing a number of variables (15) which measure different aspects of the same concept (political awareness). I have therefore performed a factor analysis on these variables. 
I would now like to transform the results of my factor analysis into an index. More specifically, I would like to create a single variable indicating political awareness out of the first three factors that I obtained, which together explain 75% of variance. 
Is this possible? How can I do this?